# Buscar aruivos FORA da pasta public no laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

tudo bem? Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira simples no php/laravel para buscar arquivos salvo em uma pasta sem ser a public, por exemplo, existe arquivos que eu não quero que sejam acessados, então vou manda-los ao usuário via Back end e será enviado via AJAX,  isto é possível?

Pensei em usar a biblioteca Storage do laravel, mas não sei se ela atende isso.

Estrutura de pasta:

[image: Estrutura de pasta:]

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar sim os "Storages" do laravel, mais especificamente a funcionalidade de link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).